# Service-worker not working on Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, vuejs3, service-worker

I'm currently facing a problem setting up a service worker for my vue3 application run by node. I've managed to reach a situation where the service worker is running and perfectly working on every Chromium browser and also on Safari, but it never worked on Mozilla Firefox browsers, classic edition, and developer.

This is the situation of my code:
this is how i register my service-worker

```
try {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
      "service-worker.js",
      {
        scope: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development" ? "/" : "../sw"
      }
    );
    registration.update();
    if (registration.installing) {
      logger("Service worker installing", "info", "Service Worker");
    } else if (registration.waiting) {
      logger("Service worker installed", "info", "Service Worker");
    } else if (registration.active) {
      logger("Service worker active", "info", "Service Worker");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger(error, "error", "Failed service worker registration");
  }
}
```

this is where i send through a message the data that are used by the service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then((registrations) => {
  const activeWorker = registrations[0].active;
  activeWorker.postMessage({
    headers: {
      Id:
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
          ? `${userStore().role}`
          : `${userStore().auth.id_token}`
    },
    api_url: process.env.API_URL,
    request_id: response.data.request_id,
    isRequest: false,
    type: this.selected.type,
    vat_code: this.company.vat_code
  });
});
```

and this is the part where i handle the message i receive from the service worker:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
    let indexToRemove = documentStore().pending_visure.findIndex(
      (v) => v.request_id === event.data.request_id
    );
    if (event.data.error) {
      try {
        documentStore().pending_visure[indexToRemove].status = "error";
      } catch (error) {
        logger(
          error,
          "fatal",
          "Failed removal of purchased visura from pending array"
        );
      }
      await raiseAlert(event.data.error);
    } else {
      try {
        documentStore().pending_visure.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      } catch (error) {
        logger(
          error,
          "fatal",
          "Failed removal of purchased visura from pending array"
        );
      }
      await raiseAlert(event.data);
      await requestStore()
        .fetchAll()
        .then(() => {
          documentStore().fetchAll();
        });
    }
  });
}
```

the idea behind the service-worker is that i invoke it to make a polling every 15 seconds and whenever it receives an object it will send a message back to the app and will raise a notification.

At the current state, the sw works perfectly fine on Chrome, Edge, Brave, and Safari, but not on Mozilla Firefox. It does correctly register the worker, activate and update, but it will never receive the data to start it, on the browser it will always say that is "stopped", and never goes on running unless I manually activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should force the service worker who is waiting to become an active service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  ....
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```